# In Google Sheet, replace the comma with a period and add EUR

Tags: google-sheets, formula, spreadsheet

Can you please tell me how to do it?

In Example No.1, you need to add a € sign before the number, and reduce the number of digits after the dot

Should show as: **€ 1.80**

```html
=ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(importXML("https://www.globalpetrolprices.com/Austria/", "//*[@id='graphPageLeft']/table[1]//tr"), 3 ^ 1, 4)
```

In Example No.2, you need to change the comma to a period and leave the number of zacks after the period
Should show as: **€ 0.00**

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ICQyiU9w-yHPynjJnx2S25Xah0GsFH5yzjATVSuZLVw/edit#gid=496450573

```html
=QUERY(IMPORTXML("https://fuelo.eu/?convertto=eur", "//table[@class=('table table-striped table-hover tablesorter')]//tr"), "Select Col1, Col2, Col6, Col10 label Col1 'Countries', Col2 'Gasoline', Col6 'Diesel', Col10 'AutoGas'")
```

Comment: for example #2, it depends on your region. In US/GB, you will get a number like 1.839 which means one thousand eight hundred and thirty nine! In that case will have to divide per one thousand and change the format! so please share a spreadsheet to solve that issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Example #1, try

```
=query(ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(importXML("https://www.globalpetrolprices.com/Austria/", "//*[@id='graphPageLeft']/table[1]//tr"), 3, 4),"FORMAT Col3 '€ 0.00', Col4 '€ 0.00'",1)
```

[image]

Example #2

```
=query(query(QUERY(IMPORTXML("https://fuelo.eu/?convertto=eur", "//table[@class=('table table-striped table-hover tablesorter')]//tr"), "Select Col1, Col2/1000, Col6/1000, Col10/1000 "),"select * format Col2 '€ 0.000',Col3 '€ 0.000',Col4 '€ 0.000' ",1),"label Col1 'Countries', Col2 'Gasoline', Col3 'Diesel', Col4 'AutoGas'",1)
```

[image]

Comment: My Sample Table https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ICQyiU9w-yHPynjJnx2S25Xah0GsFH5yzjATVSuZLVw/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Mike Steelson Example 1 works, thank you)

Comment: take a look at example #2

Comment: I changed a bit my proposal to get the right labels

Answer (score 0):

Mike Steelson I took formula and shortened it Query
Now it looks like this:

```
=QUERY(QUERY(IMPORTXML("https://fuelo.eu/?convertto=eur", "//table[@class=('table table-striped table-hover tablesorter')]//tr"),
"Select Col1, Col2/1000, Col6/1000, Col10/1000 
format Col2/1000 '€ 0.00',Col6/1000 '€ 0.00',Col10/1000 '€ 0.00'"), 
"Select Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4 
label Col1 'Country', Col2 'Gasoline', Col3 'Diesel', Col4 'AutoGas'")
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).